# Creating an Algorithm From Pressing A UIButton to Change the UIView

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I'm creating a quiz app, and I was wondering instead of using multiple **if statements**, I could make an algorithm that uses an **int** to alternate between **UIViews** when you click a **UIButton**. With multiple **if statements** the code would look something like this:

```
IBAction NextQuestion; {

    Question++; //QUESTION IS THE int FOR THE ALGORITHM.

    if (Question==2) {
        self.view = PlayView2; //PlayView2 is the UIView I'm switching to.
        }

    if (Question==3) {
        self.view = PlayView3; //PlayView3 is the UIView I'm then switching to after the next object/UIButton is pressed.
        }
```

and so on...

The **IBAction** is connected to multiple **UIButtons** to change the view. The goal is I want to change the **UIView** algorithmically instead of multiple **if statements** Thanks for your help!

Comment: How about adding your views to an array, and get a random number between 0 and array.count-1?  Then you could get your view:  `View = [array objectAtIndex:randomNumber];`.  No if statements required whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
myViewsArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: PlayView2, PlayView3, ..., PlayViewN, nil];

    -(UIView*) nextView {
       if( Question < [myViewsArray count] )
           return [myViewsArray objectAtIndex: Question++];

       return nil;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be switch case??

```
switch(Question) {
    case 2: self.view = PlayView2;
            break;
    case 3: self.view = PlayView3;
            break;
}
```